# JavaScript: replace param with a local variable?

Tags: javascript, performance

If I have a funtion like this:

```
function xyz(b)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
        // do something with b items...
    }
}
```

... wouldn't it be more memory-friendly if I were to assign b to a local variable inside of that function before working with its items?

```
function xyz(b)
{
    var c = b;

    for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
    {
        // do something with c items...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do never lose time in this stuff, you will always mess up somewhere else, trust me, maybe if it does this will affect performance 0.0001%

Comment: it wont be efficient. b is already a  local variable just like c. It'll be less efficient because the javascript engine has to intepret var c = b and waste a cpu cycle. What a waste. lol.

Comment: @KMC Even if it is not, this will never affect drastically performance of any code!

Comment: It would probably be slightly less "memory-friendly" since you are creating a copy or new reference to `b`. Also, unless `b` contains millions of elements and the function `xyz` is called multiple times per second, you don't have to worry about the performance of this function.

Comment: that's true. It's still a bad practice to have another set of local variables for each param and makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example both `b` and `c` are local variables since they only exist in the function. So your code will actually be a bit less performant.

Side note - if you want your code to be more performant you should calculate `c.length` only once for the whole for loop. In your example you're calculating it for every iteration of the loop. Instead you can do as follows:

`for (var i = 0, cLen = c.length; i < cLen; i++)`

This way it calculates it only once before starting the loop.